# Extra Information in JNDI Definition

Tags: java, jndi, web.xml

I'm developing a web application and it is to be deployed on Apache Tomcat 6.0. Application will be connecting a lot of databases (almost 25) so in order to manage the `Connection`s, I'm using a context.xml file located under **META-INF**. So far so good, and here is what a Resource Definition looks like:

```
<Resource 
  name="jdbc/XX"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="XXX"
  password="XXX"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXX"
  maxActive="8"
  maxIdle="4"/>
```

Given this definition, a Connection object is created correctly.

What I'd like to know is **if I am able to add extra information in this definition**, such as `projectName`, **and reach it from the context**(or somewhere else). Something like the following:

```
<Resource 
  name="jdbc/XX"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="XXX"
  password="XXX"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXX"
  maxActive="8"
  maxIdle="4"
  projectName="Cool Project"/>
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could define a naming convention and add an Environment element for each of your resource :

```
<Environment name="XX_projectName" 
             value="Cool Project"
             type="java.lang.String" 
             override="false"/>
```

In your code, you would access it via

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
String projectName = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/XX_projectName");
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Environment%20Entries for details.